# My application shows me black screen on real device but runs perfectly on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, ios-simulator

I'm coding an application with SwiftUI and Firebase.
My application works very well on simulators, but as soon as I  put it on a real device (like the iPhone X that I own) the application shows me a black screen.

Additionally when I put the application on my phone, 2 errors in the code appear. This does not prevent the application from building and launching, but it always shows a black screen.

[[image: Bugs with real simulator]]
[[image: Application launches]]

Here is the proof that there are no bugs with simulators:

[image: Works fine]

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you cleaned the build folder and deleted derived data?

Comment: Try to remove errors before running app.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, links and images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question because they cannot search for a matching error. Lastly, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). As far as your code goes, the error clear states there's an issue with your AppDelegate but it's not included.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is warning that in two places the code is using a String that could contain a `nil` i.e. be undefined for whatever reason. If it is a `nil` would that cause the Firestore query to lock-up? Check what is with the debugger.

In terms of the simulator vs real device - dirty install state from previous testing might be hiding problem - do a full reset on the simulator to eliminate.